# How to disable an action link after one click using jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have an jsp page. There is an action link. I want when the user click on the action link some action is performed with the action related class AND also simultaneously the link should get disabled for any other 2nd click. and the user should remain on the same page. Also a message should be displayed 'the link is disabled' on the same page Can someone give some code  or any means how to do it.? thanks..

Comment: Can someone solve this problem..? thanks.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641662/doccookie-is-not-getting-saved-instantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. How the script works is explained in the comments.

#### DEMO

http://jsfiddle.net/insertusernamehere/hp45v/

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // add a handler for the click event to the specific element
    $('#action_link').click( function(event) {

        // write that message
        $('#action_message').text('The link is disabled.');

        // do/call your action here (like ajax or some DOM stuff)
        $('#action_response').text('Something happened here');

        // release the event handler that it won't fire again
        $(this).unbind('click');

        // prevent default action of the link - this is not really necessary as the link has no "href"-attribute
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

#### HTML

```
<a id="action_link">Action link</a>
<div id="action_message"></div>
<div id="action_response"></div>
```

#### Extension

If you have multiple of those links with different actions you could use a class for all links like:

```
<a class="action" data-action="load">Action 1</a>
<a class="action" data-action="view">Action 2</a>
```

and rewrite the JavaScript function to:

```
// add a handler for the click event to all elements with the class 'action'
$('.action').click( function(event) {

    if ('load' == $(this).attr('data-action')) {
        // your action here (like ajax or some DOM stuff)
        $('#action_response').text('The action was: load'); 
    }

    if ('view' == $(this).attr('data-action')) {
        // your action here (like ajax or some DOM stuff)
        $('#action_response').text('The action was: view'); 
    }

    // release the event handler that it won't fire again
    $(this).unbind('click');
});
```

Comment: Hi, Can u solve this problem too.. ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641662/doccookie-is-not-getting-saved-instantly